# Why universal G-bundles are contractible?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $G$ be a nice topological group and $E\to B$ a universal $G$-bundle. I'm interested in a proof of contractibility of $E$ using only the universal property of it. I also know that if there is a contractible $G$-bundle, then all of others are also contractible, but does there exist a direct proof not using a special construction of contractible universal $G$-bundles?

Comment: If $B$ represents the functor «$X$ → principal $G$-bundles on $X$», then $E$ represents the functor «$X$ → principal $G$-bundles on $X$ with a fixed section». This functor is trivial, so $E$ is contractible.

Comment: @GrigoryM I know that a map to $E$ gives a section of a $G$-bundle but I'm having trouble to prove your correspondence for homotopy classes of maps. Could you please write a complete answer? thanks!

Comment: Nobody has an answer for this important fact?

Comment: Worth mentioning there is a nice note that I found which includes a proof of this fact... https://math.uchicago.edu/~dannyc/courses/alg_topol_2013/F_bundle_notes.pdf

Comment: @chikurin nice reference! thanks!